# Are Insert Intention Locks blocked by IX locks?

Tags: mysql, locking, database-deadlocks

I am investigating a reproducible deadlock in our MySQL (INNODB) database caused by the concurrent execution of the same update. The update is

```
UPDATE our_db.uploads
    SET Status = -2
    WHERE Status = 0
      AND InstallationId = 28;
```

'Uploads' is a relatively simple table with an auto-increment ID, foreign key to the installations table (InstallationId), and simple number field for Status. There is also a non-unique index on (InstallationId,Status). Running this statement twice concurrently often causes a deadlock. The relevant INNODB STATUS output is the following

```
---TRANSACTION 315703, ACTIVE 21 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 62, OS thread handle 804, query id 161323 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Searching rows for update
UPDATE our_db.uploads
        SET Status = -2
        WHERE Status = 0
          AND InstallationId = installation
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 21 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 314 page no 6 n bits 80 index InstallationId_Status of table `our_db`.`uploads` trx id 315703 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 6 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 800000000000001c; asc         ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 2: len 8; hex 8000000000000026; asc        &;;

------------------
TABLE LOCK table `our_db`.`uploads` trx id 315703 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 314 page no 6 n bits 80 index InstallationId_Status of table `our_db`.`uploads` trx id 315703 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 6 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 800000000000001c; asc         ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 2: len 8; hex 8000000000000026; asc        &;;

---TRANSACTION 315702, ACTIVE 21 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 6 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 43, OS thread handle 28664, query id 161319 localhost 127.0.0.1 root
UPDATE our_db.uploads
        SET Status = -2
        WHERE Status = 0
          AND InstallationId = installation
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 21 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 314 page no 6 n bits 80 index InstallationId_Status of table `our_db`.`uploads` trx id 315702 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 6 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 800000000000001c; asc         ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 2: len 8; hex 8000000000000026; asc        &;;

------------------
TABLE LOCK table `our_db`.`uploads` trx id 315702 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 314 page no 6 n bits 80 index InstallationId_Status of table `our_db`.`uploads` trx id 315702 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

Record lock, heap no 6 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 800000000000001c; asc         ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 2: len 8; hex 8000000000000026; asc        &;;

RECORD LOCKS space id 314 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `our_db`.`uploads` trx id 315702 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 6 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 13; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000026; asc        &;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000004d136; asc      6;;
 2: len 7; hex 710000013e11b0; asc q   >  ;;
 3: len 5; hex 99ae08e7a5; asc      ;;
 4: len 5; hex 99ae08e7a5; asc      ;;
 5: len 8; hex 800000000000001c; asc         ;;
 6: len 6; hex 546573742d2d; asc Test--;;
 7: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 8: SQL NULL;
 9: SQL NULL;
 10: len 4; hex 7ffffffe; asc     ;;
 11: len 8; hex 99ae090740000000; asc     @   ;;
 12: len 8; hex 99ae090744000000; asc     D   ;;

TABLE LOCK table `our_db`.`appstore_installations` trx id 315702 lock mode IS
RECORD LOCKS space id 85 page no 3 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `our_db`.`appstore_installations` trx id 315702 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 16 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 17; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 800000000000001c; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000036d08; asc     m ;;
 2: len 7; hex a80000011c0110; asc        ;;
 3: len 5; hex 99ae08e795; asc      ;;
 4: len 5; hex 99ae08e795; asc      ;;
 5: SQL NULL;
 6: SQL NULL;
 7: SQL NULL;
 8: SQL NULL;
 9: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 10: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 11: len 9; hex 546573742d4a455241; asc Test-JABC;;
 12: len 9; hex 546573742d4a455241; asc Test-JABC;;
 13: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 14: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 15: len 1; hex 00; asc  ;;
 16: len 1; hex 00; asc  ;;

RECORD LOCKS space id 314 page no 6 n bits 80 index InstallationId_Status of table `our_db`.`uploads` trx id 315702 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 6 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 800000000000001c; asc         ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 2: len 8; hex 8000000000000026; asc        &;;
```

If I am reading this right then transaction 2 is waiting for an Insert Intention lock. However, the only lock transaction 1 has is an IX lock on the table. Do IX locks block Insert Intention locks? Am I reading this right? Can someone show me the documentation for that, and help understand the reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 0):

What you show in your question is not a deadlock. It's only a lock wait.

You show two transactions both with IX locks, waiting to acquire gap locks.

There must be another session that is holding onto the X lock on the table. It may be doing a long-running DDL statement, such as `ALTER/TRUNCATE/DROP/RENAME TABLE`, `CREATE/DROP TRIGGER`, or else have previously run a `LOCK TABLES ... WRITE`.

Comment: If I enable deadlock detection, then it points to these two transactions as being in deadlock.

Comment: Nevertheless, what you have posted in your question above does not show a deadlock.